# How to Get the Webpage Title of Chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome

Using python, is there a way to obtain the title of the current active tab in Chrome?

If it is impossible, getting the list of titles of all tabs also works for my purpose.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple way of getting the title of a the current tab using Python,

You could use BeatifulSoup

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com"))
print soup.title.string
```

Or if your using Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(YOUR_URL)

print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)
driver.refresh()
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I want is a program to passively monitor/log what the user is viewing in Chrome (rather than interfering by opening a new browser or specifying a url such as in urlopen("URL") or driver.get(YOUR_URL)).